# Return redirect() is not taking me to desired method

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am building a blog in CodeIgniter 3. I want to redirect from one controller to another controller when user is authenticated but `redirect()` is not working.

I have tried all the solutions given in Stack Overflow but no one works for me. Check my code and tell me where is the problem. Thanks in advance.

`MY_Controller` is my core controller extended from `CI_Controller`.

#### Login_c.php

```
class Login_c extends MY_controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('public/admin_login_v');
    }

    public function admin_login() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User name', 'required|trim|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password' , 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            $login_id = $this->login_model->login_valid($username,$password);

            if( $login_id ){
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $login_id);
                return redirect('admin_c/dashboard');

            } else {
                echo "user not authenticated";
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view('public/admin_login_v');
            // echo validation_errors();
        }
    }
}
```

#### admin_c.php

```
<?php
// ob_start();

class Admin_c extends MY_Controller {
    public function dashboard() {
        $this->load->view('public/admin_dashboard');
    }
}
```

#### config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/ci_blog";
```

#### Error

> HTTP 500 internal server error

Comment: `500 internal server error` is just what your web server shows on the front end - it also logs much more detail for you to work out what the problem is.  What do your Apache, PHP and CodeIgniter logs show?

Comment: Also, note that you don't `return` a `redirect()`, you [just `redirect()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect).  Don't think this causes a 500 though.

Comment: Have you tried changing the filename from admin_c.php to Admin_c.php

Answer (score 0):

There could be plenty of reasons for this.
Firstly you could diagnose the problem using display errors

If you drop

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

At the top of your document then run it in the browser this could return the reason it is not working.

As for the `redirect()` function itself, have you looked at what parameters it requires? 
I like to use software called PHPStorm, you can get it as a free trial, when defining a function it will tell you what parameters the function requires and in what order. Very helpful.

If none of this helps here is a redirect function i like to use, which you can drop in your document and call back to where ever you like

```
$site_prefix = 'http'; //This could equal http or https depending on your ssl
$site_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //You could replace $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] with your actual hostname like 'example.com'

    function redirect_to($page){

            global $site_prefix;
            global $site_url;

            if($page == 'home'){
                header("Location: {$site_prefix}://{$site_url}/");
            }
            elseif($page == ''){
                header("Location: {$site_prefix}://{$site_url}");
            }
            else{
                header("Location: {$site_prefix}://{$site_url}/{$page}");
            }
        }
```

You can then call in this function like so

```
redirect_to('admin/dashboard.php');
```

Or if you're using pretty urls

```
redirect_to('admin/dashboard');
```

I like to use the globals instead of using the `site_url` variable within the function because i tend to use them throughout the site.

If worst comes to worst you can always run a PHP redirect using

```
header("Location: http://example.com/mypage.php");
```

I know this was very long winded but I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
  redirect('admin/dashboard.php','refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

load session library in constructor.

Your code would be like

```
class Login_c extends MY_controller {


public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('public/admin_login_v');
}

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function admin_login() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User name', 'required|trim|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password' , 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $login_id = $this->login_model->login_valid($username,$password);

        if( $login_id ){
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $login_id);
            return redirect('admin_c/dashboard');

        } else {
            echo "user not authenticated";
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('public/admin_login_v');
        // echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

}

**DO NOT PRINT ANYTHING BEFORE using redirect() **

Answer (score 0):

Have you got routes defined in your App\Config\routes.php
Also try:
return redirect('Admin_c/dashboard');

I know its too late to answer but keeping it if it helps any other.